# Why is simulink data type conversion block altering the data when it should be typecasting?

Tags: matlab, simulink, types

I am attempting to typecast some data from int32 to single.  I first tried using the 'Data Type Conversion' block with single output data type and the Stored Integer option.  However, I found that the datatype conversion block is not typecasting the data the way I expect it to.  Am I using the block incorrectly, or is it failing to work as it should?

> temp1 (pre conversion):     uint32: 1405695244     single:
>   1728356810752.000000     binary: 01010011110010010011010100001100
>
> temp2 (post conversion):     uint32: 1319604842     single:
>   1405695232.000000     binary: 01001110101001111001001001101010

By the way, I have gotten around the issue by using an embedded Matlab block to perform the typecasting operation.

Comment: What version of MATLAB/Simulink are you using?

Answer (score 0):

"Convert" block crop the number. 
I would suggest to use Matlab Embedded function with "typecast".

function out_single = typecasting(in_uint32)

```
out_single = typecast(in_uint32, 'single');
```